# JQuery save clicks on specific class and show later

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show how much product's of a specific type are added, so i'm saving this in a variable. Now when you click on a different product I rest this variable and show how much clicks this new product reserved, only when you now click on the first product it needs to add 1 to the old total

- So 2 clicks on the first product, shows 2
- now 3 clicks on the second product, shows 3
- 1 more click on the first product, needs to show 3 but now is
  showing 1

how can i save the variable for later use and recall it?

```js
i = 0;
_this = null;
$(".addtocard").click(function() {
  i++
  if (this == _this) {
    _this = this;
    $(_this).closest(".productbox").find(".productbox-add").addClass("addedproduct");
    $(_this).closest(".productbox").find(".productbox-add").text(i + "x");
  } else {
    i = 1;
    _this = this;
    $(_this).closest(".productbox").find(".productbox-add").addClass("addedproduct");
    $(_this).closest(".productbox").find(".productbox-add").text(i + "x");

  }
});
```

```css
.addtocard {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productbox">
  <span class="addtocard">add to card</span>
  <br>
  <span class="productbox-add">Number</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="productbox">
  <span class="addtocard">add to card</span>
  <br>
  <span class="productbox-add">Number</span>
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is you are using a global counter which is shared to store the count for each product.

You can use the [data-api](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store the count for each item

```js
$(".addtocard").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    count = $this.data('count') || 0;
  count++
  $this.closest(".productbox").find(".productbox-add").addClass("addedproduct").text(count + "x");
  $this.data('count', count)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productbox">
  <span class="addtocard">add to card</span>
  <br>
  <span class="productbox-add">Number</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="productbox">
  <span class="addtocard">add to card</span>
  <br>
  <span class="productbox-add">Number</span>
</div>
<br>
```